# CSS Diagonal line has whitespace on zoom

Tags: html, css

I created a diagonal line on a container div: when I zoom a whitespace (or maybe a margin) of 1px appears on the bottom of my div showing a piece of the background color of the parent div.
I have been facing this problem for days without a solution.

You can view it here: https://codepen.io/Sirvasile/pen/GyPapb

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 212px;
  background-color: orange;
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 40px 100vw;
  border-color: transparent transparent white transparent;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

This is a screenshot of the div without zoom.
[image]

This is a screenshot of the div when the web page is zoomed (> 100%) (experienced using Google Chrome and Safari):
[image]

P.S. I already tried using transform: translateY(1px) but I can't accept it as a solution because using it the div has no more a perfect diagonal line.

Comment: I tried both in Chrome and IE Edge. Could not recreate the issue. I do not see a white space. Any additional info is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've dealt with similar problems, though not this exact one, and I believe the cause, ultimately, is a rounding error that ends up leaving a spare pixel. It's a browser bug that you won't fix with CSS alone, and `transform: translateY(1px)` might be the only guaranteed fix to the above code.

But, we can probably avoid that bug just by creating this effect by different means.

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 212px;
    background-color: orange;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 40px), 0 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 40px), 0 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing `100%` with`100vw` ?
Sometime using these two different values for the same element can resolve to a weird scroll appearing.